# Creating a C# Windows Service to host a WCF service integrated with a legacy C++ backend

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, soap, service

We are building a C# Windows Service to host a WCF service integrated with a legacy C++ backend that will service requests made to the WCF service.

Is it possible to construct the C# front-end so that it accepts a minimum SOAP request (possibly a default query in the envelope) and then pass the entire SOAP message (or at least the XML contents of the envelope) to the C++ backend for interpretation so that the details of the interface don't have to be duplicated in C# or exposed to clients of the service (which would know which requests are available and the data structures required for each)?

We would also need to be able to construct partial XML in the C++ backend which the C# front-end would then insert into a SOAP envelope to make the response.

Is it sensible to target using SOAP  for this or would it simplify things to use a simpler XML structure (home-grown or alternate standard) that can be passed in its entirety to the backend where the entire response would be constructed?

Thanks for reading, any advice welcomed :)